# Properly referencing documents in mongodb (relations)?

Tags: mongodb, data-structures, mongodb-query, database

I'm having an difficulty understanding the way to reference documents properly in MongoDB. Say i have following collections:

- schools
- classes
- students

I need Students to be referenced to a class, and a class to be referenced to a shool. This would be very simple to store and query in SQL via additional relational table.
What would be the best approach for MongoDB, in order to efficiently query referenced data in both directions?

Can the Mongo structure be efficient enough for all of the following scenarios combined?

1. Query all classes that belong to a school.
2. Query a school that belongs to a class.
3. Query students that belong to a class.
4. Query students that belong to a school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Single reference

In a single reference structure, like `student.classId`, `class.schoolId`, `school.id`, operations 1 and 3 can be done in a single `find` operation. 2 and 4 can be done in two:

1 Query all classes that belong to a school.

```
db.classes.find({schoolId: <school-id>})
```

2 Query a school that belongs to a class.

```
const schoolId = db.classes.findOne({_id: <class-id>}).schoolId;
const school = db.schools.findOne({_id: schoolId});
```

3 Query students that belong to a class.

```
db.students.find({classId: <class-id>})
```

4 Query students that belong to a school.

```
const classesForSchool = db.classes.find({schoolId: <school-id>});
const classIds = classesForSchool.map(class => class._id);
const students = db.students.find({classId: {$in: classIds}});
```

#### Alternative

You might consider having two collections: one with schools (having a nested array of objects for classes), and one with students. In that case, all 4 are single queries. You can mantain data integrity by adding a unique index like so:

```
db.schools.createIndex({'classes._id': 1}, {unique: true})`
```

All queries would then look like so:

1 Query all classes that belong to a school.

```
db.schools.findOne({_id: <school-id>}).classes
```

2 Query a school that belongs to a class.

```
db.schools.findOne({'classes._id': <class-id>})
```

3 Query students that belong to a class.

```
db.students.find({classId: <class-id>})
```

4 Query students that belong to a school.

```
db.students.find({schoolId: <school-id>})
```